# Alter matched item in for loop leaving the rest untouched

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Not sure how to even title this question but i tried my best to condense it.
I have a key / value array that i need to loop through and print out as options to a select field. My issue is that i need to match an ID with a value in the array and give that option a selected attribute.

** Cannot use ES6 syntax **

My array:

```
groups = 
[
 { name:"eng1",
   value: "12"
 },
 { name: "eng2",
   value: "247"
 },
 { name: "eng23",
   value: "112"
 },
];
```

My loop:

```
var targetGroupId = 247;
for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if (groups[i].Value = targetGroupId) {
        html += "<option value'" + groups[i].Value + "' selected='selected'>" + groups[i].Name + "</option>";
    } else {
        html += "<option value='" + groups[i].Value + "'>" + groups[i].Name + "</option>";
    }
}
```

I need to print out all three items in the array as options. However the item matching `targetGroupId` needs to have the selected attribute.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: **You have three issues:** 1. comparing values with `=` rather than `===` 2. You're using capitalized keys 3. comparign string with numbers.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track, just need to change the case of `Value` to `value` and `Name` to `name` then in your condition, change from an assignment operator to equality (`==` or `===`)

Comment: Apologies, the capitalization was a typo on my part. However, modifying the operator looks like it solved my issue. Thank you very much, i must have been thinking too deeply into the loop itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You have three issues

1. Comparing values with `=` rather than `===` .
2. You're using capitalized keys.
3. Comparing string with numbers.

```js
var groups = [{name: "eng1",value: "12"},{name: "eng2",value: "247"},{name: "eng23",value: "112"},],
    html = '',
    targetGroupId = 247;
    
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  if (/*Convert to number ->*/+groups[i].value === targetGroupId) {
    html += "<option value'" + groups[i].value + "' selected='selected'>" + groups[i].name + "</option>";
  } else {
    html += "<option value='" + groups[i].value + "'>" + groups[i].name + "</option>";
  }
}

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following issues with your code:

1. You are using `Value` property instead of `value`. Replace `Value` with `value` everywhere in your code.
2. Second, you need to correct this statement

   ```
   if (groups[i].Value = targetGroupId) {
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   if (groups[i].value == targetGroupId) {
   ```

I've used `==` to auto-coerce the values for the comparison because `targetGroupId` is a number whereas `value` in the object is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The keys name is case sensitive.So `Value` & `Name` need to be match the case

Also the `value` is string but the `targetGroupId` is integer. So need to convert the string to number or vice versa.

Beside `groups[i].Value = targetGroupId` is not right , you need to do the quality check instead of assigning the value

```js
var groups = [{
    name: "eng1",
    value: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "eng2",
    value: "247"
  },
  {
    name: "eng23",
    value: "112"
  },
];
var html = '';
var targetGroupId = 247;
for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  if (+groups[i].value === targetGroupId) {
    html += "<option value'" + groups[i].value + "' selected='selected'>" + groups[i].name + "</option>";
  } else {
    html += "<option value='" + groups[i].value + "'>" + groups[i].name + "</option>";
  }
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<select id='test'></select>
```